# unable to resolve 'SynchronizedConverter' in dot net core 2.0 web app when using dinkToPdf

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to integrate DinkToPdf dot net core wrapper to an existing dot net core 2.0 web app following the instructions on GitHub. But IConverter/SynchronizedConverter/PdfTools are not getting resolved. Guess I am missing a using statement but cannot determine what..

This is what I have done ..

1. Used .nuget to install DinkToPdf.
   The package was successfully installed to users/userprofile/.nuget/.. /dinktopdf folder
2. downloaded the 64 bit dll's from github (rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/v0.12.4/64 bit/) to the project folder
3. updated the startup.cs ConfigureServices() method by adding services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));

at which point I get the errors with " are you missing a using .. "

I also tried the following, and verified that the path as well as LoadUnmanagedLibrary() are successful.

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
var context = new CustomAssemblyLoadContext();
context.LoadUnmanagedLibrary(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "libwkhtmltox.dll"));

```
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IConverter), new SynchronizedConverter(new PdfTools()));
```

}

What is it that I am missing .. thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

resolved. Restarting visual studio fixed the issue. May be a caching issue, would like a better reason if possible.